# Triggering screen monitoring calls all dio request in mobx store class

Tags: flutter, uitextfield, mobx, dio

When I trigger screen monitoring(mostly when I use textfield), it calls all the dio request I use in the application. I don't know why it occurs and what it is related to. Does anyone face this kind of issue or know anything about this problem?

I tried to debug it, but I don't have any unneccesary call, I don't use any unneccesary observable widget. It happens, even in a class I didn't initilize the related mobx classes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, that's because I was using the didChangeDependencies override function, I fixed it by moving my code from didChangeDependencies to init function. But, it might still be a problem for someone who wants to use didChangeDependencies function.